# upgrade to Magento2.3.1 with porto theme version 3.7.1 showing white screen

Tags: magento2.3, porto-theme

upgrade to Magento2.3.1 with porto theme version 3.7.1  showing white screen 
on Product page and Category pages.
Other page working fine

`PHP Version 7.1.27`

There no error of php and js in console.

> `No content in Body tag`

Comment: Upgrade your PHP version to 7.1.3~7.2.0. Otherwise, some PHP function is working as expected

Comment: did php update solved the issue. I have 7.2.11 but still showing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2.3.1 is compatible only with **PHP 7.2.X** and it is certified on **PHP 7.2.11**. So please upgrade your PHP version to 7.2. You can find more information regarding this in [Magento 2.3.1](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.3.1OpenSource.html) release notes.